# Getting location of scanned text in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 "This is some text".scan("some")
```

I would like to be able to scan for a string like above but have the method return the location of the text, so that it could be called like this:

```
 This is some text"[8..11]
 => "some"
```

Is there a built-in function for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.  Do you mean to ask that if you supply `"This is some text".scan("some")` you'd like to get [8..11]?  Please explain.

Comment: My understanding is you want the index range of the substring?

Answer (score 2):

The index method will do this for you:

```
"This is some text".index('some')
=> 8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the position, using `scan` isn't the appropriate method. Per the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan), `scan` searches the entire string for matches, and returns all that are found.

Instead:

```
/\b some \b/x =~ "This is some text"
=> 8
```

or:

```
"This is some text" =~ /\b some \b/x
=> 8
```

`\b` is a word-boundary, which is the space between any character not in the `\w` character-class and one that is in `\w`. The `x` flag lets me put white-space into the pattern, but it is insignificant, and `x` isn't necessary, it's a convenience to make the pattern more readable.

```
target = 'some'
str = 'This is some text'
pos = str =~ /\b #{ target } \b/x
str[pos, target.size]
=> "some"
```